# Twilo How to Handle the Timeout in Dial

Tags: go, twilio

I need to record a voice of my clients who is try to reach one of our advisors. This should happen when there is timeout

1. User calls -->Number-----> If timeout --> say(Record your message)--> on end of the recording it should call the recordingStatusCallBack
2. User Call --> Number -->  answer call success --> On end of the call it should call method. Not sure where should we put the action either on number (statuscallback) or on the dial Action verb?

To achieve this I am try with the below twiML

```
<Response>
   <Dial callerId="+123124" record="true" timeout="10">
  <Number 
  statusCallback="https://<123134>.ngrok.io/ttwilio/callStatusCallBack" 
  statusCallbackEvent="completed" 
  statusCallbackMethod="POST">+1232424/Number>
 </Dial> 
 <Say>Please Record you message</Say> 
   <Record 
     recordingStatusCallback=
      "https://<123134>.ngrok.io/ttwilio/callStatusCallback" 
       recordingStatusCallbackMethod="POST"/>
</Response>
```

This works fine when there is a timeout but when the call is successfully ended twilio still ask for the user to "Please Record you message"

How to achieve this task?

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The behaviour of [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) when there is no [`action` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action) is to continue with the TwiML below it once the call is finished, whether by timeout or through a successful call.

If you add a URL as the `action` attribute, then the behaviour changes and `<Dial>` will always make a request to the `action` URL once the call is completed. The important difference here though, is that the URL will be called with a [`DialCallStatus` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action-dial-call-status-values) that will be one of "completed", "answered", "busy", "no-answer", "failed" and "canceled". This way you can check if the call was busy or not answered and return the TwiML for recording a message. Or if the call was completed successfully, you can just return [`<Hangup/>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/hangup).

Let me know if that helps at all.